# How to write and compile stored proc in Documentdb in Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, c#-4.0, azure-cosmosdb

How can I write and compile stored proc in DocumentDb using Document Db script explorer or Query explorer

Answer (score 1):

You certainly can. CRUD operations on sprocs, triggers and UDFs are supported in the latest Script explorer.

[image]

EDIT: You can now execute them from the script explorer.